# How to handle "too small to represent as a normalized machine number" when plotting a figure

Tags: plotting, warning-messages, precision-and-accuracy, machine-precision

I am trying to plot a figure by the following codes:

```
Plot[(27 2^((-2 + a)/(-1 + a)) 5^(a/(-1 + a)) 7^(1/(1 - a)) 
      a^2)/((-1 + a) (4 + 9 a)), {a, 1.001, 3}]
```

When running the above program, the warning appeared:

> General::munfl: `1/7^960.765` is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.

How can I fix this problem? I have tried to set a higher `WorkingPrecision` value, but it didn't work.

Comment: I'd just add `Quiet@Plot[...`  it does not affect anything in terms of the plot. It is just saying it is too small of a number.

Comment: @Nasser Thanks. I knew this method, but I think this method only "escaped" the  problem rather than really solved it. I would like to know if there is other ways to fix the problem.

Comment: Machine numbers have a gap between zero and the next larger number. For Plotting purposes this warning may be ignored and do as Nasser suggest.

Comment: `{a, 1 + 1/100, 3}`

Comment: @cvgmt Pls note that the starting point is 1.001, not 1.01.

Comment: @YaHe  We need not start from 1.001 since  `Limit[(27 2^((-2 + a)/(-1 + a)) 5^(a/(-1 + a)) 7^(1/(1 - 
         a)) a^2)/((-1 + a) (4 + 9 a)), a -> 1, 
 Direction -> "FromAbove"]`

Comment: @cvgmt Yes, this function converges to zero as a ->1. But I still hope there is some way to fix the mentioned problem which occurs when a is very close to 1 (e.g., a=1.001 or 1.002).

Comment: @YaHe It's impossible to do even for the simplest example. `Plot[1/x^1000, {x, .001, 1}]`

Comment: @cvgmt It's possible. To be more specific: `Plot[With[{a = SetPrecision[a, 16]}, a (27 2^((-2 + a)/(-1 + a)) 5^(a/(-1 + a)) 7^(1/(1 - a)) a^2)/((-1 + a) (4 + 9 a))], {a, 1.001, 3}]` Please refer to the suggested duplicate to understand the reason.

Comment: @xzczd Many thanks! Your proposal works quite well!