Understanding strange numeric behavior of "Plot" command
I have the following cumbersome expression which I wish to plot:
A = 786432 (q^4 - 120 q^5 + 7640 q^6 - 338720 q^7 + 11646096 q^8 - 
   328819456 q^9 + 7895703552 q^10 - 165050873856 q^11 + 
   3053360248832 q^12 - 50595008069632 q^13 + 757827906109440 q^14 - 
   10333477974179840 q^15 + 128997342720321536 q^16 - 
   1480985386705944576 q^17 + 15695685105063133184 q^18 - 
   154035048151782653952 q^19 + 1403469736782073204992 q^20 - 
   11898484017325394745344 q^21 + 94038100044845070391296 q^22 - 
   693968105937868316614656 q^23 + 4788478276076389408518144 q^24 - 
   30930675961343240041070592 q^25 + 
   187218903103881412654006272 q^26 - 
   1062780943130610577130389504 q^27 + 
   5662051673736088489565259776 q^28 - 
   28325885051341076131988520960 q^29 + 
   133125419272677780052733444096 q^30 - 
   587951640570027514005661483008 q^31 + 
   2440670766160769046934877319168 q^32 - 
   9523510319574754085551706210304 q^33 + 
   34929158396599706012480346292224 q^34 - 
   120396707701417643995563677319168 q^35 + 
   389903422032528830960987151753216 q^36 - 
   1185885277134903245954719579701248 q^37 + 
   3385659304273380734691413262925824 q^38 - 
   9067177002053151851336397822361600 q^39 + 
   22760424213164343342359984965287936 q^40 - 
   53499825536705541829906791326023680 q^41 + 
   117625078712287448215908340249657344 q^42 - 
   241576828717279438662862339930324992 q^43 + 
   462767169508885620675381062353158144 q^44 - 
   825405355785878867019328755583680512 q^45 + 
   1368055363451585936121846389554544640 q^46 - 
   2102222590265923466936444281417629696 q^47 + 
   2987119197930408315464148506890207232 q^48 - 
   3913038188858975632065942889301016576 q^49 + 
   4709228140908122634415624691260588032 q^50 - 
   5185655532419578258990804556826279936 q^51 + 
   5200271098255970541779455887391064064 q^52 - 
   4722849284613217871936838980673208320 q^53 + 
   3858957103792363625759586419401031680 q^54 - 
   2814309349515395765051463619544350720 q^55 + 
   1814226707537458630452656751343828992 q^56 - 
   1021351522312965618539118675709919232 q^57 + 
   494446606821177126376991001428361216 q^58 - 
   201697332359729627463979377037934592 q^59 + 
   67423182045526049412264213307981824 q^60 - 
   17735341292919688733098963969769472 q^61 + 
   3442544940249458840652585508012032 q^62 - 
   438419639794671295859452549267456 q^63 + 
   27481535567992899381688847220736 q^64)

If I just do the usual thing and call
Plot[A, {q, 0, 1/3}, PlotRange -> All]

I get the following messy graph, full of numerical artifacts.

However, if I sample specific values as in, for instance, A /. q -> 1/3 // N I get nice results (the value 0.0672034 in this case). Moreover, if I do a list plot, by calling
ListPlot[A /. q -> # & /@ Table[st, {st, 0, 1/3, 1/1000}], Joined -> True, DataRange -> {0, 1/3}]

I get the expected graph:

My question is the following. Why does this happen with Plot? I was naively thinking that it would do more or less the same as what I did with ListPlot with the potential exception of cleverly sampling the points, so that it takes more points in intervals where the function varies more. However, it seems that something more is going on here.
Then, is it possible to modify something so that the same graph can be obtained with Plot?
Thank you.

The first few error messages from Plot, which you didn't mention in your post, tell you that some of the numbers involved in your calculation of up to 64th powers can't be cleanly dealt with using only MachinePrecision==16 digits. So tell it to use enhanced precision like this Plot[A,{q,0,1/3}, PlotRange->All,WorkingPrecision->1024] and your plot shows up just fine

That's great thanks! It works indeed, although the same error messages appear. Could you exaplin to me why this happens with Plot but not ListPlot?

As to the warning message, it's explained in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/212168/1871 See also https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/276307/how-to-handle-too-small-to-represent-as-a-normalized-machine-number-when-plott?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment690006_276307
